# Loop for all worksheet in a workbook is not working

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I would to copy paste the first cell of a sheet trough the last row for all sheets in a workbook and my code is not working, the code is done on the active sheet only.

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5

 Dim ws As Worksheet

 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

     Range("A2").Copy Destination:=Range("A3:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

 Next ws

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Looping the worksheets does not make them active. You want something like this.

```
    Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim iIndex As Integer

    For iIndex = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count
        Set WS = Worksheets(iIndex)
        With WS

        'Do something here.
            .Range("A2").Copy Destination:=.Range("A3:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        End With
    Next iIndex
```

You could use the ws in your loop, but I always set the object.

```
 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     ws.Range("A2").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A3:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
 Next ws
```

Comment: You technically don't need to do any "Activating", I've revised your answer slightly :)

Comment: I was making that change also.  Thanks David