# Loop through sheets and delete hidden columns

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason I can't get the following code to loop through all of the sheets in the workbook.  It deletes the hidden columns on whichever sheet I am on when I execute the code but it doesn't go through all of the sheets in the workbook.  Can someone help?  Thanks!

```
Sub delete_hidden_columns()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        For i = 256 To 1 Step -1
            If Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete Else
        Next

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: put `ws.` in front of each `Columns(i)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop for all worksheet in a workbook is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089572/loop-for-all-worksheet-in-a-workbook-is-not-working)

Comment: FWIW: the `= True` in the if is redundant.

Comment: I know it is a duplicate question of the link you provided but the solution did not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an "End If" statement.

Also put ws. in front of your Columns

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

     For i = 256 To 1 Step -1
         If ws.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden Then 
             ws.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete 
         End If
     Next

Next ws

Set ws = Nothing
```

Comment: Since the OP's IF was in one line it did not need the `End If`

Comment: True :)  but the dangling "else" just seems sloppy.